# WPF apply a colour theme based on a binding value

Tags: wpf, silverlight, binding, styles

I have a rather detailed user control has is made up of several sections, these sections has a specific blue theme applied to them, but I want to swap all of the Grids/Borders/Rectangles/etc... colours to be a green version of the same theme based on a binding in the DataContext.

Obviously I could use a converter for each Fill/Background property of the elements, but that seems very annoying.

In my converter (or XAML), can I apply a `Style` somehow to my user control that will just set the Fill/Background/etc... properties of my elements, essentially applying a colour theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this in a style, making all Rectangles have a certain color.

In a resource dictionary I have:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Windowsbackground" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.259"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF7691CD" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

And then in my user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.Views.TestView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    MinHeight="300" MinWidth="300" Background="{DynamicResource Windowsbackground}">
```

Comment: so I would have to apply different style to all the different elements that require these colours and gradients? Im assuming so, just wanted to check

Comment: You can add your own styles for colours and gradients that each of your control then again uses, to make it easier to change colours or gradients in the future.

Comment: But still you need to either explicitly override default of each "normal" control you use, or you have to make your own styles like explained above. I recommend the approach above!